# array declaration causes GDB halt

Tags: c, gdb

I'm getting this error message whenever I try to declare an array:

> Unable to open 'cygwin.S': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (\home\keith\src\mingw\gcc-build\gcc-6.3.0-mingw32-cross-native\mingw32\libgcc......\src\gcc-6.3.0\libgcc\config\i386\cygwin.S)).

when I try to create the file (click a pop up in vscode) I get another error that says:

> Unable to write file (EntryExists (FileSystemError): Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\home\keith\src\mingw\gcc-build\gcc-6.3.0-mingw32-cross-native\mingw32')

```
Result removeFromDictionary(Dictionary* d, int key){
    int size = d->keysSize;
    int tempKeys[size];
    int tempValues[size];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

the debugger stops working when it reaches "int tempKeys[size];"

how can I fix this?

Comment: make clean?  This is not an error due to the code you show, it's due to something in your compiler toolchain setup/environment

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: @AShelly Well how can I check the settings? should I delete minGW and reinstall everything again?